# Gather totals for each unique cell in a column in a MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here is the current code used to extract data from the database
`$query = "SELECT username,time,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) as timestamp,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(active) as activestamp,IP FROM ".$table_name." WHERE success='1' ORDER BY active DESC";`

Here is a sample set of data (with all unimportant fields removed)
`ID | username

_01 | admin

_02 | admin

_03 | bob

_04 | jill`

What I want is the total number of times each user appears, for example:
`admin (2)

bob (1)

jill (1)`

I need to add something along the lines of this `COUNT(IF(name = 'admin', 1, NULL)) AS login_totals` to the original query I showed you, but I can't figure out the correct code. The name admin in my sample has to be the current username, so would I just put "username" there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: I added the `count(*) and the group by`

```
 $query = "SELECT username,time,
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) as timestamp,
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(active) as 
activestamp,IP, count(*) 
FROM ".$table_name." WHERE success='1' 
group by username 
ORDER BY active DESC";
```

take a look to this Blog: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

Answer (score 0):

add `COUNT(username)` in `SELECT` clause and `GROUP BY username` at the end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   username,count(username)
   FROM ".$table_name." WHERE success='1' 
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY active DESC";
```